# selecting meshes

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm having issues with selecting multiple faces for colors. I can't use it with ALT. I can do it with SHIFT no problem but my mesh is complex and I need different colors. I check all viewport, viewport overlay settings for default or short addon. I can't find anything different. I can't select all these faces for different materials holding down shift. It will mess up. Any suggestions. Thanks

[image: plane]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the material panel  you can have multiple material slots.  You can have multiple materials slots per object.  In Edit Mode for a given material slot there will 3 additional actions available

- Assign
- Select (Select by Material assigned)
- Deselect.

So you can assign colors to faces incrementally. You do not need to go from zero to perfection in one shot.  There is the undo keystroke as well.  So in the slowest case you could select only one face and click Material Assign, but you can probably manage more.

Blender has vertex groups in the object panel.  You can select from that panel.  You can CRUD. Create Read Update Delete.

Thus you can save a complex face or edge or vertex group and recall it at will with a single click. Since you can save your selection incrementally you can slowly bring your selection to perfection.

Search here at BSE for vertex group or the famous video website .. 
Search Terms ...  Blender Vertex Groups.

Comment: Thanks I'm grouping them now, it's going to be slow so many faces going in same row. I'll just start with lights first.

Comment: Please remember to use such as circle select and box select and loop select.  These are terms which can be searched at BSE and the famous video website which has the name that rhymes with noonube.